# typescript @aws-sdk version-3, how to upload files using S3Client from browser using OpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I obtained `OpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` in my server by following the url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html

```
const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: process.env.AWS_API_VERSION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION});
  const Logins:Record<string, string> = {};
  Logins[process.env.AWS_IDENTITY_CUSTOM_PROVIDER] = 'custom';
  const params = {
    IdentityPoolId: process.env.AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    Logins
  };
cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, (err, data) => {

  console.log(data);

});
```

Now I am trying to upload images to my s3-bucket using the `IdentityId and Token` obtained from the above response.

But I couldn't find any API to upload files using the above mechanism. I am using the S3Client https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3

I tried with aws-sdk version-2 also, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated which guide me to upload images to S3 from browser using developer-authenticated-identities